# Скорость записи в файл

Tags: c#, файлы

Всех приветствую.

Написал алгоритм дешифровки прошивки. Вроде все хорошо, но не учел скорость записи в файл. В общем я считываю по четыре байта из прошивки, ибо так нужно и после их дешифровки пишу в новый файл. Но вот в чем проблема, прошивка весит ~71мб и запись в файл происходит очень долго. Как можно оптимизировать для быстрой записи?

Comment: - **Покажите код.**
- Я правильно понимаю, что данные для записи вы строите в памяти, а только после этого дампите на диск?
- Вообще, с запись файлов ~100 мегабайт должна происходить довольно быстро. Вы уверены, что именно запись происходит долго, а не, например, ваша дешифровка-по-4-байта?

Comment: Считываю оригинальные 4 байта, дешифрую и тут же записываю в новый файл.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Привет.

Запись и чтение с диска малыми "порциями" влечёт за собой большое количество вызовов API, каждый из которых сравнительно долгий. Попробуйте буферизовать запись: записывать по 4 байта в буфер в памяти (например, 64КБ длиной), и буфер периодически "скидывать" на диск. Класс [BufferedStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx) умеет это автоматически, просто оберните в него `FileStream`.

**Дополнение:** И да, обратите внимание на комментарии и убедитесь, что проблема чисто в скорости записи готовых данных.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую! :)
Скорость дешифровки вроде нормальная, вот например 26кб данных дешифруются за секунду.

Comment: При скорости дешифрования 26КБ/с 71МБ будет теоретически обрабатываться ~45 минут. Вы всё ещё уверены, что узкое место - скорость записи на диск?

Comment: Попробуйте запись в `MemoryStream` вместо диска. Если сильно быстрее не станет - тормоза **не** в записи на диск.

Comment: Весь файл обрабатывается примерно за 2~3 мин.
Спасибо за советы, сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: Попробовал MemoryStream, сильно быстро не стало. Пожалуй да, Вы правы!